# Strange web page rendering

Tags: html, css

Why 'main' part border is jammed up against 'aside' part? Why there is no breathing room between 'aside' part and 'main' part border?
[image]

```css
aside {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}

main {
  border: 3px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <h2>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore...</p>
</aside>
<main>
  <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry...</p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the default value for property `box-sizing` is set to `content-box` by default which indicates that `height` and `width` of elements are calculated based on the size of content and not its `padding`, `margin` and `border`. So you should use `box-sizing: border-box;` for each element you wish its `padding`, `margin` and `border` (size) value affect its final dimensions.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}

main {
  border: 3px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <h2>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore...</p>
</aside>
<main>
  <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry...</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Am I right that real width of the 'aside' part is 25% + 10px? content-box says that real size would be content (specified by width preperty) + padding + border + margin.

Comment: True indeed. When using `content-box`, dimensions (in this case width) will be only based on the content size (in this case you set the content width using `width: 25%;`). Value for size of `padding`, `margin` and `border` will be added independently to final width of the element.

Answer (score 1):

The other way to get a similar result is to forgo `float` altogether and use a layout grid. In the example below, I've defined a 2xN grid and set the `aside` to use the left column, all rows, while `main` inhabits the first row of the right column, with the left column defined as 25%.

The number of rows comes out to 3 right now, only because I've defined `aside` as taking up 3 rows. There are `auto` rows, so there are as many as are needed.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% auto;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}

aside {
  grid-column: 1/1;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  padding: 10px;
}

main {
  grid-column: 2/2;
  grid-row: 1/1;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <h2>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore...</p>
</aside>
<main>
  <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry...</p>
</main>
```